# Changing file descriptor limit in C (OSX)

Tags: c, macos, file-descriptor, setrlimit

I want to increase the maximum number of file descriptors available to my C program, which is running on OSX 10.7. I've added the following code to my project, but it fails!

```
struct rlimit limit;
if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit))
{
    perror("Failed to get limit");
    return -1;
}

printf("%llu, %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur, limit.rlim_max);
limit.rlim_cur *= 4;
printf("%llu, %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur, limit.rlim_max);

if(setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit))
{
    perror("Failed to set limit");
    return -1;
}
```

It prints this the log:

```
4864, 9223372036854775807
19456, 9223372036854775807
Failed to set limit: Invalid argument
```

The maximum limit seems a little too high. What's going on?

Comment: You can specify error by printing `errno` value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from man setrlimit:

> setrlimit() now returns with errno set to EINVAL in places that historically succeeded. ...
>   Use "rlim_cur = min(OPEN_MAX, rlim_max)".

The OPEN_MAX is defined as **10240** in <sys/syslimits.h>

So it failed to set rlimit_cur to 19456.

Comment: That's what I get for reading the man page for setrlimit from an online linux reference instead of the OSX man pages...